# ERR > sh: 1: exec: usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX --version: not found

Tags: php

When I try below command inside a controller it gives me this error.
***$process = new Process(['usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX --version']);***
I also Tried ***$output = exec('echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S "usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX --version" 2> /dev/null');***
Creating Symlink and chmod 777 doesn't help at all.

Comment: At a guess, you should be passing the path and the `--version` argument as separate elements, `['usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX', '--version']`. Dependant on the working directory, ou may also need to make the path absolute i.e. `/usr/local` rather than `usr/local`.

Comment: opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found. Tried this but no luck so far . "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773296/libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found"

Comment: So I see you have asked [a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428422/opt-lampp-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found) for that