# opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: lamp

```
ERR > /usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX)
/usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX)
/usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/pdf2htmlEX)
```

As you can see those versions are already installed,still getting this error.

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.33
GLIBC_2.25
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.32
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.34
GLIBC_2.4
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question so that it is an actual question? As it stands, you're putting 100% of the work on a community of volunteers without any context, which is quite unfair. Help us help you by providing details such as: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) whether this is a new installation or not (2) whether this has happened after a software update or not (3) any other details that may make it possible to determine how best to help you with this missing library issue 

Comment: it's not even clear if you're showing us the GLIBCXX versions in `/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6` or in your system's own `libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: These Packages are installed in system's own as you said But when i see in  /opt/lampp/lib. I can't see those required versions that are giving errors. My $LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib.